# What exceptions does boost mapped_file_source throw?

Tags: c++, exception, boost, memory-mapped-files

Boost mapped_file_source seems to throw an exception in case of e.g. file not found. What exception classes exactly does it throw? It doesn't seem to say in the documentation, unless I'm missing something.

Edit: test case:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source file;
    file.open(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Care to post a short example that displays the behavior?

Comment: Who downvoted Supreme_D's answer (now unfortunately deleted)? I checked just now and he's right, it is a subclass of std::exception (though I would still be interested to know the exact class).

Comment: I downvoted the answer because it was a lazy attempt to garner reputation and didn't actually answer the question, library exceptions often derive from `std::exception`. If you let the exception fall through its type should be printed, at least it does on gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case the mapping fails, the code

```
mapped_handle_ = 
        ::CreateFileMappingA( 
            handle_, 
            NULL,
            protect,
            0, 
            0, 
            NULL );
    if (mapped_handle_ == NULL)
        cleanup_and_throw("failed create mapping");
```

will eventually throw a

```
boost::iostreams::detail::throw_system_failure(msg);
```

i.e. a subclass of `std::exception`. In this case it should be `std::ios::failure`:

> BOOST_IOSTREAMS_FAILURE
>
> Expands to std::ios_base::failure if available, and to a suitable
>   derived class of std::exception otherwise.

Reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iostreams/src/mapped_file.cpp

Comment: This is very badly documented in the docs for boost memory mapped files, consider adding a section in the documentation.